# Can I use JavaFX with Scala Native?

Tags: javafx-8, javafxports, scala-native, scala-bindgen

Given that [there are compiled versions of the JavaFX SDK for mobile](http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/downloads/) (iOS and Android), how feasible is it to generate Scala bindings from those files, and be able use them from a Scala-Native application?

Answer (score 1):

I don;t have any specific knowledge on JavaFX in particular. Neither I've tried to compile it to a native library. However, there's a general answer:

> Given you have a native library which adheres to `C` calling conventions (which means that you can call easily from `C`), you can call it easily from `Scala Native` too.

In a nutshell, all you have to do is defining the bindings for it. And I suppose it is where problems start and (I suppose) it is the context of your question. Rephrasing your question:

> Can I automagically generate bindings for JavaFX?

Well... it depends... if you have a header file (`.h`)... the answer is: very probably yes. Otherwise: no, `scala-bindgen` does not understand anything else.

**Note:** at the time of this writing, `scala-bindgen` is still a work in progress and not yet really usable.

Comment: Eduardo: Please let me know if there's some sort of JavaFX.h or something like that. This use case would be very interesting in the testsuite of ``scala-bindgen``.

Comment: I have done a bit of digging and have found nothing. RoboVM was able to do it, but I have been unable to understand how by looking at their source code, or JavaFX's source code.

Answer (score 0):

No, Scala Native currently doesn't provide JavaFX API.

Comment: I know it is currently not possible to use the JavaFX library, as is, from a standard Java distribution. My question was about the library in its compiled form to native code, which already exists, and has been used before with RoboVM.